# When i am inserting an image to my table.My image exceeds the column. The table's width becomes more than the section.How do I resolve this issue

Tags: html, css, html-table, styling

When i am inserting an image to my table, and since the image is obtained using snipping tool. My image exceeds the column. The table's width becomes more than the section.How do I resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css. This should make your image take it’s containers width.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```